# Auth for 2 different tables in cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to use two tables for login one for admin and another user. Tables have different fields.
For that reason I don't want to use same table for authentication. How do I differentiate the authentication for login in cakephp 3.0

Comment: Do you want both user classes to be able to log in via the same controller and action, or will you have a different controller and/or action for admin login?